# Assigning set value to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I have list `company_list_present` with duplicate values whihc looks like `[u'SOUTH ASIAN ENTERPRISES LTD', u'SPICEJET LTD', u'SPICEJET LTD']`

I have assigned this list to dictionary

```
record['company_present'] = set(company_list_present)
```

When I return it as json I see it get returned like this -

```
 'result': {'suspected': 95.941691412119113, 'unsuspected': 4.0583085878808909}, u'company_present': set(['DR REDDYS LABORATORIES LTD', 'ASTRA MICROWAVE PRODUCTS LTD'])
```

`see u'company_present' value`

how to assign distinct list to company_list_present?

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to set company_list_present variable with distinct values? or shoudl company_list_present be a key in your dictionary?

Comment: You should create a [mcve] so we can reproduce this weird result.

Answer (score 3):

You just want to return you set to a list ? then

```
record['company_present'] = list(set(company_list_present))
```

Comment: Yes, this is what wanted to know